# Figuring out TensorFlow's BoostedTrees layer-by-layer approach

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been reading the article associated with the implementation of boosted trees in TensorFlow in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.11555.pdf), where a layer-by-layer approach is discussed

> ... and novel Layer-by-Layer boosting, which allows for stronger trees
>   (leading to faster convergence) and deeper models.

Though no where in the article this approach is discussed.
I am pretty sure that the [`n_batches_per_layer` parameter passed in the BosstedTreesClassifier/Regressor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BoostedTreesRegressor#__init__) is related to this concept.

My questions are

1. What is this approach? Any source to read more about it?
2. What is the meaning of the `n_batches_per_layer` parameter?
3. What should I set the `n_batches_per_layer` parameter to follow the standard training scheme of boosted trees?

Answer (score 3):

n_batches_per_layer is how many batches do you want to use to train for each layer (i.e. a given depth in your tree).  It is basically a portion of the data to use to build 1 layer, measured in batches. For example if you set your `batch size = len(train_set)` and `n_batches_per_layer = 1`, then you will use the entire train set for each layer.

So I would recommend if their dataset fits into memory then set batch_size = len(train_set), the number of `n_batches_per_layer = 1`. Otherwise set it to `int(len(train_data)/batch_size)` -- though you could try experimenting with a smaller number for faster training.